# How can I find the potential created by spherical capacitor with dielectric material?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

If we have a spherical capacitor with inner radius or r1 and outer radius of r2, with charges (+/-)q on them and there is a dielectric material (with constant e) in between them with.

What kind of a potential would this create outside the entire capacitor? in the region with the dielectric? and inside the entire thing?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gauss's law (see this [Link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesph.html#c2)), the solution is as follow,
$$
\Phi (r) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{q}{{4\pi \varepsilon {r_1}}}\,\,\,\,for\,\,\,r \le {r_1}}\\
{\frac{q}{{4\pi \varepsilon r}}\,\,\,\,for\,\,\,{r_1} \le r \le {r_2}}\\
{0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,for\,\,\,r \ge {r_2}}
\end{array}} \right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple as this is a standard equation for the capacitance. You will have

$$C=\epsilon C_0$$

being $C_0$ the capacitance in vacuum. For a full set of formulas in different geometrical configurations see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance).

Answer (score 0):

You can write down these fields directly without calculating anything because the field of a charged sphere is the same as that of a point charge outside the sphere and zero inside the sphere.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potsph.html